# Splitting amount between different accounts

Tags: sql-server-2012, case-statement

I am trying to write a report that will split the total amount for each empid into their primary account and their secondary account based on the limits of the primary account. Below is some code to make some sample tables, along with what i have so far for the code, and the desired result set displayed at the bottom. The portion of the code that is commented out is the plain English of what I am unsure how to code.

I am trying to write this on SQL Server 2012.

```
Create Table Test

(
Empid Int not null,
Account Varchar(25) not null,
MaxAmt Int not null
)


Create Table Test2

(
EmpID Int not null,
TtlAmt int not null
)


Insert Into Test
Values (748,'Primary',50)

Insert Into Test
Values (748,'Secondary',99999)

Insert Into Test
Values (750,'Primary',50)

Insert Into Test
Values (750,'Secondary',99999)

Insert Into Test
Values (752,'Primary',60)

Insert Into Test
Values (752,'Secondary',99999)

Insert Into Test2
Values (748,80)

Insert Into Test2
Values (750,75)

Insert Into Test2
Values (752,20)

Select * from Test

Select * from Test2


Select
     B.EmpID
    ,A.Account
    ,Case
        When A.Account = 'Primary' and B.TtlAmt >= A.Maxamt Then A.MaxAmt
        When A.Account = 'Primary' and B.TtlAmt <= A.MaxAmt Then B.TtlAmt
        When A.Account = 'Secondary' and B.TtlAmt >  /* Max of Primary */ Then B.TtlAmt - /* Max of Primary */
        When A.Account = 'Secondary' and B.TtlAmt <= /* Max of Primary */ Then Null
        Else 'Error'
    End as Amount


From Test as A
    Join Test2 as B
        on A.EmpID = B.EmpID


/*************** Desired Result would look like below *******************/

EmpID           Account             Amount
748             Primary             50
748             Secondary           30
750             Primary             50
750             Secondary           25
752             Primary             20
752             Secondary           Null
```

This is the start as there will end up being a total of up to 25 accounts max for each empid while some empid will only have 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
     B.EmpID
    ,A.Account
    ,Case
        When A.Account = 'Primary' and B.TtlAmt >= A.Maxamt Then A.MaxAmt
        When A.Account = 'Primary' and B.TtlAmt <= A.MaxAmt Then B.TtlAmt
        When A.Account = 'Secondary' and B.TtlAmt > A2.MaxAmt Then B.TtlAmt -  A2.MaxAmt
        When A.Account = 'Secondary' and B.TtlAmt <= A2.MaxAmt Then Null
        Else 'Error'
    End as Amount


From Test as A
    Join Test as A2 on A.EmpId = A2.EmpId and A2.Account = 'Primary'
    Join Test2 as B
        on A.EmpID = B.EmpID
```

from comment below, easiest way would be like this

```
Select
     B.EmpID
    ,A.Account
    ,sum(Case
        When A.Account = 'Primary' and B.TtlAmt >= A.Maxamt Then A.MaxAmt
        When A.Account = 'Primary' and B.TtlAmt <= A.MaxAmt Then B.TtlAmt
        When A.Account = 'Secondary' and B.TtlAmt > A2.MaxAmt Then B.TtlAmt -  A2.MaxAmt
        When A.Account = 'Secondary' and B.TtlAmt <= A2.MaxAmt Then 0
        Else 0
    End) as Amount


From Test as A
    Join Test as A2 on A.EmpId = A2.EmpId and A2.Account = 'Primary'
    Join Test2 as B
        on A.EmpID = B.EmpID
group by B.EmpID, A.Account
```

Comment: This appears to be very close to the answer I need. However It gives 3 rows of data for each Empid / Account Combination(748 Primary 3x and 748 Secondary 3x...) Also the 3rd entry for Seconday on each Empid is lower than the previous ones by 10 the only exception being the Empid of 752 since it's secondary was null

Comment: My mistake, missed your second part.  Sum the Amount field (remove error) and group by EmpId and Account, see edit.

Comment: Perfection. I still don't fully understand how you are able to link a table to itself to make this happen but that is pretty sweet. If i interpret it right basically we are making a derived tabled through the join but with only the primary accounts so we can grab the maxamt of the Primary account while looking at the Secondary account due to the chain of joins on EMPID across B > A> A2. Don't think I would have found this so thank you very much.

Comment: So when I expand this to include up to 25 accounts per employee I will need to setup a join that makes A3, A4, A5...A25 each of them filtered to just that account and then in the case have it remove all the previous accounts each time right? I mean this code is awesome but that is going to be a lot of typing. Good thing i get paid by the hour :)

Comment: Nope, the join into A2 will be enough.  Basically what its doing it taking that  primary account row and sticking it on every record in Test2.  That data sits there unaltered with the primary account max that you can access on every row